# form with all calculated fields - Access 2013

Tags: ms-access

The form with all calculated fields are working properly then when i closed & re-opened the file all calculated fields became #name?. I tried to C&R but it didn't work. I tried to go to design view and create a button, text box etc and save it and the formulas will work again. but then if i save and exit the error occur again. Please help me as I am tired of thinking what mistake I did where in I've been using my database for a week already without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new empty database and import all objects from the old. Compile and save.

If that doesn't work, revert to a backup or rebuild the form.